# Modeling total participation with trigger and function

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have two tables I'm trying to model total participation between in order to handle all new recipes need to have ingredients:

```
CREATE TABLE Recipes
(
    recipe_id INTEGER,
    title VARCHAR(20),
    total_time INTEGER,
    prep_time INTEGER,
    CHECK (prep_time < total_time),
    cook_time INTEGER,
    CHECK (cook_time < total_time),
    difficulty VARCHAR(20),
    method VARCHAR(20),
    directions VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (recipe_id) 
)

CREATE TABLE Includes
(
    recipe_id INTEGER,
    ingredient INTEGER,
    brand VARCHAR(20),
    quantity VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (recipe_id, ingredient, brand),
    FOREIGN KEY (recipe_id) REFERENCES Recipes,
    FOREIGN KEY (ingredient, brand) REFERENCES Ingredients 
)
```

My trigger:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER totalPartRecipeIngredient
AFTER INSERT ON recipes
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION check_Ingredients()


CREATE FUNCTION check_ingredients()
RETURNS trigger
AS $check_ingredients$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO recipes(recipe_id) VALUES (NEW.recipe_id);
    INSERT INTO includes(recipe_id) VALUES (NEW.recipe_id);
    COMMIT;
    IF (NEW.recipe_id NOT IN (SELECT Includes.recipe_id
                    FROM Includes))
    THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION ‘recipe must have ingredients’;
    END IF;

RETURN NEW;
END;
$check_ingredients$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Running into some issues here. Originally with the code above I get errors because some of the values in Recipes are NOT NULL.

When I switch the function to receive all of the attributes like:

```
INSERT INTO recipes(recipe_id, title, total_time, prep_time, cook_time, difficulty, method, directions, description) 
VALUES (NEW.recipe_id, NEW.title, NEW.total_time, NEW.prep_time, NEW.cook_time, NEW.difficulty, NEW.method, NEW.directions, NEW.description)
```

and the same for Includes, I get :

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "recipes_pkey"

I want the database system to not launch the trigger until the very end of this transaction, once hopefully the includes tuple for a recipe that I am inserting has already been created. How can I get around these issues?

Answer (score 0):

AFTER INSERT trigger : the inserted rows are inside the table. So the first insert of your trigger function trys to insert the same row... Thats violates the PK

Use a INSTEAD OF insert trigger or remove the fisrt isnert inside the trigger function